# I want a Rotary Encoder to make 10 steps at once, but my code isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: rotary-encoder, joystick

I'm using a rotary encoder on my Arduino Micro, that is supposed to do single steps or ten steps at once, depending on which position a switch is in.

The Rotary: https://www.reichelt.de/drehimpulsegeber-15-impulse-30-rastungen-vertikal-ec11mvbfx-p315144.html?&nbc=1 (on this site are pictures and datasheets as well.)

The Switch:
https://www.reichelt.de/miniatur-kippschalter-ein-aus-ein-3-a-250-v-goobay-10023-p285990.html?&nbc=1

Wiring: (image following later)

> ```
>         1--------Pin16 |  Pin A3----Switch
> Rotary  2--------GND   |  GND-------|
>         3--------PIN17 |
> ```

The rotary encoder gives no output, neither the Serial.print nor the gamecontroller. Also there is no output in either switch position.

**EDIT:**
After using arrays and loops like @jsotola teached me, it works nearly the way its supposed to, but sometimes, although the switch is off, it clicks ten times.
The code looks like this shortened **now**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Joystick.h>
#include <BasicEncoder.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>

int EncoderPins[] = {
  4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
};
int EncoderCount = 8;

BasicEncoder encoder4(EncoderPins[6], EncoderPins[7], HIGH, 2);

void timer_service() {
  encoder4.service();
}

#define joyButton16 EncoderPins[6]  // Rotary4
#define joyButton17 EncoderPins[7]  // Rotary4
#define joyButton18 21              // HDG_SWITCH := Switch to select between single and 10 steps

//Joystick(Joystick HID ID, Joystick Type, Button Count, Hat Switch Count, Include X, Include Y, Include Z, Include Rx, Include Ry, Include Rz, Include Rudder, Include Throttle, Include Accelerator, Include Brake, Include Steering)
Joystick_ Joystick(0x15, JOYSTICK_TYPE_JOYSTICK, 19, 0,
                   true /*X*/, false/*Y*/, false/*X*/,
                   false/*Rx*/, false/*Ry*/, false/*Rz*/,
                   false/*Rudder*/, false/*Throttle*/, false/*Acc*/,
                   false/*Brake*/, false/*Steer*/);

const bool initAutoSendState = true; // code is sends continuously and doesnt wait for polling

int EncoderState[] = {
  0, 0, 0, 0
};

void setup() {
  for (int q  = 0; q < EncoderCount; q++)
  {
    pinMode(EncoderPins[q], INPUT_PULLUP);
  }

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Joystick.begin();

  Timer1.initialize(100);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(timer_service);
}

void loop() {
  GET_CHANGE();

  int CurrentButton18State = !digitalRead(joyButton18);
  switch(CurrentButton18State){
    case 0: 
      switch(EncoderState[3]){
        case  1: clickButton(15); Serial.println(EncoderState[3]); break;
        case -1: clickButton(16); Serial.println(EncoderState[3]); break;
        } break;
    case 1:
      switch(EncoderState[3]){
        case  1: clickTen(15); break;
        case -1: clickTen(16); break;
        } break;
  }
}

void clickButton(int pin) {
  Joystick.setButton(pin, 1);
  delay(2);
  Joystick.setButton(pin, 0);
}

void clickTen(int pin) {
  for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
  {
    clickButton(pin);
    Serial.println("step: "); Serial.println(ii);
    delay(10);
  }
}
void GET_CHANGE()
{
  for(int E = 0; E<4; E++)
  switch(E) {
    case 3: EncoderState[E] = encoder4.get_change(); break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce the code to the minimum that produces the behaviour you describe. Is this code meant for the Arduino Uno? If so, Arduino pin A3 (your switch pin) is physically the same as pin 17 (one of your encoder pins). Pins 0 and 1 are the Serial RX/TX pins, which you can't use for other things if you need input/output on the Serial port.

Comment: @StarCat, it says Arduino Micro

Comment: @StarCat since "A3" is the marker on the board itself, i thought it would be easier to understand, ofcourse every analog pin can be used as an digital (in the code i do so). I postet the complete sketch, because i dont know, if the problem maybe is in an other part then the two switches.

The Buttons on pins 0/1 may get wired with a voltage distributor on an other pin

Comment: why are you talking about selecting between 10 steps and 1 step when you cannot get the encoder to work? ... please focus your question to the problem

Comment: No output, neither in on nor in the off position of the switch

Comment: Which `rotary encoder` and `switch` are you referring to? When I google those words, it seems there are millions of choices. Is the switch built in to the rotary encoder? I am having trouble seeing your rotary encoder from my computer. How about sharing a link to the manufacturer, or datasheet, or a picture of it?

Comment: *I postet the complete sketch, because i dont know, if the problem maybe is in an other part then the two switches.* - if you reduced the code to the encoder part only you would find that out, wouldn't you?

Comment: @jsotola the Rotarys above, which have no switch connected, are working.

Comment: @VE7JRO added them

Comment: Again, please reduce your source to the minimum that still reveals your problem.

Comment: 1. I second the other commenters: you are posting too much code. Please, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 2. May be unrelated to your problem but, your code assumes `BasicEncoder::get_change()` always returns −1, 0 or 1. This may not always be the case, especially considering that you have quite a few `delay()` in your code.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I read the link you posted and will reduce the code this afternoon (with help of Jsotola). get_change() should either give 1 or - 1 if rotary is used and 0 if it stands still, doesn't it?

Comment: Re the value returned by `get_change()`: as [stated in the documentation](https://github.com/micromouseonline/BasicEncoder#get_change), `get_change()` returns “the number of counts since the last call to the method”. If the loop executes very quickly, this will almost always be within ±1. The documentation suggests “Try adding a delay in `loop()` to see larger changes being reported.” You already have quite a few delays.

Comment: @EdgarBonet so you think i should compare if its higher or lower than 1 v -1?

Comment: And this I could put in a loop, so it pushes the button that often i rotated the switch, couldn't I?

Comment: i want to excuse for shorten the code that late, but now it is, had no time before and forgot when i wrote the question

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the question, but a tip about simplifying your code.

This is a snippet of your code.

```cpp
void loop() {

// some more code here


  int encoder1State = encoder1.get_change();
  switch (encoder1State) {
    case 1:
      Joystick.setButton(8, 1);
      delay(25);
      Joystick.setButton(8, 0);
      //Serial.println(encoder1State);
      break;
    case -1:
      Joystick.setButton(9, 1);
      delay(25);
      Joystick.setButton(9, 0);
      //Serial.println(encoder1State);
      break;
    case 0:
      break;
  }
  int encoder2State = encoder2.get_change();
  switch (encoder2State) {
    case 1:
      Joystick.setButton(10, 1);
      delay(25);
      Joystick.setButton(10, 0);
      //Serial.println(encoder1State);
      break;
    case -1:
      Joystick.setButton(11, 1);
      delay(25);
      Joystick.setButton(11, 0);
      //Serial.println(encoder1State);
      break;
    case 0:
      break;
  }
  int encoder3State = encoder3.get_change();
  switch (encoder3State) {
    case 1:
      Joystick.setButton(12, 1);
      delay(25);
      Joystick.setButton(12, 0);
      //Serial.println(encoder1State);
      break;
    case -1:
      Joystick.setButton(13, 1);
      delay(25);
      Joystick.setButton(13, 0);
      //Serial.println(encoder1State);
      break;
    case 0:
      break;
  }
  int currentButton20State = !digitalRead(joyButton20);
  int encoder4State = encoder4.get_change();
  switch (currentButton20State) {
    case 0:
      switch (encoder4State) {
        case 1:
          Joystick.setButton(14, 1);
          delay(25);
          Joystick.setButton(14, 0);
          Serial.println(encoder4State);
          break;
        case -1:
          Joystick.setButton(15, 1);
          delay(25);
          Joystick.setButton(15, 0);
          Serial.println(encoder4State);
          break;
        case 0:
          break;
      } break;
    case 1:
      switch (encoder4State) {

        case 1:
          TenRotaryStepsUP();
          break;
        case -1:
          TenRotaryStepsDOWN();
          break;
        case 0:
          break;
      } break;
  }

  //GetParamFromFS2020();
  //ShowFlightParam();

  delay(10);

}

void TenRotaryStepsUP()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    Joystick.setButton(14, 1);
    delay(25);  //for testing set on higher number e.g. 500
    Joystick.setButton(14, 0);
    Serial.println("step: "); Serial.println(i);
    delay(10);
  }
}

void TenRotaryStepsDOWN()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    Joystick.setButton(15, 1);
    delay(25);
    Joystick.setButton(15, 0);
    Serial.println("step: "); Serial.println(i);
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

It can be simplified by putting repeated code into functions.

```cpp
void loop() {

// some more code here


  int encoder1State = encoder1.get_change();
//Serial.println(encoder1State);
  switch (encoder1State) {
    case 1:
      clickButton(8);
      break;
    case -1:
      clickButton(9);
      break;
    case 0:
      break;
  }

  int encoder2State = encoder2.get_change();
  switch (encoder2State) {
    case 1:
      clickButton(10);
      break;
    case -1:
      clickButton(11);
      break;
    case 0:
      break;
  }

  int encoder3State = encoder3.get_change();
  switch (encoder3State) {
    case 1:
      clickButton(12);
      break;
    case -1:
      clickButton(13);
      break;
    case 0:
      break;
  }

  int currentButton20State = !digitalRead(joyButton20);

  int encoder4State = encoder4.get_change();
  switch (currentButton20State) {

    case 0:
      switch (encoder4State) {
        case 1:
          clickButton(14);
          break;
        case -1:
          clickButton(15);
          break;
        case 0:
          break;
      } break;

    case 1:
      switch (encoder4State) {
        case 1:
          clickTen(14);
          break;
        case -1:
          clickTen(15);
          break;
        case 0:
          break;
      } break;
  }

  //GetParamFromFS2020();
  //ShowFlightParam();

  delay(10);

}

void clickButton(int pin) {
  Joystick.setButton(pin, 1);
  delay(25);
  Joystick.setButton(pin, 0);
}

void clickTen(int pin) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    clickButton(pin);
    Serial.println("step: "); Serial.println(i);
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

You can even format your code like this.

```cpp
switch (encoder3State) {
  case  1:      clickButton(12);      break;
  case -1:      clickButton(13);      break;
  case  0:                            break;
}
```

EDIT

Also refer to the following about the use of arrays as variables, to specify pins, instead of individual variable names

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/Arrays

eg. use `lastButtonState[1]` instead of `lastButton1State` and `joyButton[1]` instead of `joyButton1`

that will allow the use of `for` loops to repeat the same action for multiple pins

```cpp
int currentButton2State = !digitalRead(joyButton2);
if (currentButton2State != lastButton2State) {
  Joystick.setButton(1, currentButton2State);
  if (currentButton2State == 1) {
    delay(1);
    Joystick.setButton(1, 0);
  }
  lastButton2State = currentButton2State;
}
```

becomes

```cpp
int currentButtonState[pin] = !digitalRead(joyButton[pin]);
if (currentButtonState[pin] != lastButtonState[pin]) {
  Joystick.setButton(pin-1, currentButtonState[pin]);
  if (currentButtonState[pin] == 1) {
    delay(1);
    Joystick.setButton(pin-1, 0);
  }
  lastButtonState[pin] = currentButtonState[pin];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jsotola, will try this when I'm back at home!

Comment: added more info

Comment: Thanks, I will try this this afternoon (also I will reduce the code in the question)

Comment: You can also handle multiple encoder steps with something like `if(encoder3State>0) while(encoder3State--) clickButton(12); if(encoder3State<0) while(encoder3State++) clickButton(13);`.